# Enable/disable authentication options after startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I want to create a custom CMS in which the admin can select all the possible login options in his admin panel. But I can only setup the third party logins for OWIN in my Startup.cs:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });
        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
            clientId: "00000000000000000",
            clientSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
            consumerKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            consumerSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            appId: "000000000000000",
            appSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
    }
}
```

I would want to be enable and disable those login options from my running app. Thus after startup. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: @WilliamEdmondson nope sorry

Answer (score 0):

Most of those login flows are triggered by the user selecting one of the auth providers from a list. You could just show/hide items from that list.

Comment: That is not what I am looking for. The admin must also be able to set the needed ids/secrets/keys for the desired login. I want to be able to build an cms dll which the user can then just put on their server and then edit it in the admin panel.

Comment: Ok, so you want a self-editing website. The most common way I've seen that done is to let them make their changes, save them to a config file, and re-cycle the site.

Comment: I want it to be most userfriendly and simpel to use, no waits for recylce etc, so I wanted to store the settings in a database. There must be a way to get to the settings of owin...

Comment: Sorry, there's no way to re-build the pipeline without re-starting the app, so you can't add or remove auth providers on the fly.If you just want to change the keys, you can technically do that by holding onto the options object for each provider and changing the options after startup.